# When I try to pull a image from docker.io with „podman pull“, I always get an error saying I need to authenticate even though I'm logged in

Tags: podman

I have a problem regarding pulling with podman from docker.io.
I try to pull rootless an image from docker.io, but every time I try to, I got a message saying, that authentication is required, but I'm in deed logged in.

I already raised a bug for that on github, but maybe someone has some additional ideas:

[Error saying I need to authenticate even though I'm logged in, when I try to pull an image from docker.io](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/14731)

Thanks you for your support in advance.

**Output of `podman login --get-login`:**

```
dennis605
```

**Output of `podman login`:**

```
Authenticating with existing credentials for docker.io
Existing credentials are valid. Already logged in to docker.io
```

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

1. login with `podman login docker.io`
2. try to pull image from docker `podman pull docker.io/jc21/mariadb-aria:latest`

I always get the message saying:

`Error: initializing source docker://jc21/mariadb-aria:latest: reading manifest latest in docker.io/library/jc21/mariadb-aria: errors: denied: requested access to the resource is denied unauthorized: authentication required`
and the image will not be pulled.

I'd expect to have the image pulled without any message saying, that I need to authenticate, because I'm already loged in.

**Output of `podman version`:**

```
Client:       Podman Engine
Version:      4.1.1
API Version:  4.1.1
Go Version:   go1.18.3
Built:        Thu Jan  1 01:00:00 1970
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

**Output of `podman info --debug`:**

```
host:
  arch: amd64
  buildahVersion: 1.26.1
  cgroupControllers: []
  cgroupManager: cgroupfs
  cgroupVersion: v1
  conmon:
    package: conmon_100:2.1.2-1_amd64
    path: /usr/bin/conmon
    version: 'conmon version 2.1.2, commit: 99eac3e82289c18465adeab5c522469ad14e5725'
  cpuUtilization:
    idlePercent: 99.82
    systemPercent: 0.08
    userPercent: 0.1
  cpus: 4
  distribution:
    codename: bullseye
    distribution: debian
    version: "11"
  eventLogger: file
  hostname: h2977318.stratoserver.net
  idMappings:
    gidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 1001
      size: 1
    - container_id: 1
      host_id: 165536
      size: 65536
    uidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 1001
      size: 1
    - container_id: 1
      host_id: 165536
      size: 65536
  kernel: 4.19.0-1160.53.1.vz7.185.3
  linkmode: dynamic
  logDriver: k8s-file
  memFree: 8273846272
  memTotal: 8589934592
  networkBackend: cni
  ociRuntime:
    name: runc
    package: containerd.io_1.6.6-1_amd64
    path: /usr/bin/runc
    version: |-
      runc version 1.1.2
      commit: v1.1.2-0-ga916309
      spec: 1.0.2-dev
      go: go1.17.11
      libseccomp: 2.5.1
  os: linux
  remoteSocket:
    path: /run/user/1001/podman/podman.sock
  security:
    apparmorEnabled: false
    capabilities: CAP_AUDIT_WRITE,CAP_CHOWN,CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE,CAP_FOWNER,CAP_FSETID,CAP_KILL,CAP_MKNOD,CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE,CAP_NET_RAW,CAP_SETFCAP,CAP_SETGID,CAP_SETPCAP,CAP_SETUID,CAP_SYS_CHROOT
    rootless: true
    seccompEnabled: true
    seccompProfilePath: /usr/share/containers/seccomp.json
    selinuxEnabled: false
  serviceIsRemote: false
  slirp4netns:
    executable: /usr/bin/slirp4netns
    package: slirp4netns_100:1.2.0-1_amd64
    version: |-
      slirp4netns version 1.2.0
      commit: unknown
      libslirp: 4.7.0
      SLIRP_CONFIG_VERSION_MAX: 3
      libseccomp: 2.5.1
  swapFree: 0
  swapTotal: 0
  uptime: 40h 55m 27.19s (Approximately 1.67 days)
plugins:
  log:
  - k8s-file
  - none
  - passthrough
  network:
  - bridge
  - macvlan
  - ipvlan
  volume:
  - local
registries:
  docker.io:
    Blocked: false
    Insecure: false
    Location: docker.io/library
    MirrorByDigestOnly: false
    Mirrors: null
    Prefix: docker.io
    PullFromMirror: ""
  search:
  - docker.io
  - quay.io
  - registry.fedoraproject.org
store:
  configFile: /home/pod/.config/containers/storage.conf
  containerStore:
    number: 1
    paused: 0
    running: 0
    stopped: 1
  graphDriverName: overlay
  graphOptions: {}
  graphRoot: /home/pod/.local/share/containers/storage
  graphRootAllocated: 321939173376
  graphRootUsed: 5339725824
  graphStatus:
    Backing Filesystem: extfs
    Native Overlay Diff: "false"
    Supports d_type: "true"
    Using metacopy: "false"
  imageCopyTmpDir: /var/tmp
  imageStore:
    number: 2
  runRoot: /run/user/1001/containers
  volumePath: /home/pod/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes
version:
  APIVersion: 4.1.1
  Built: 0
  BuiltTime: Thu Jan  1 01:00:00 1970
  GitCommit: ""
  GoVersion: go1.18.3
  Os: linux
  OsArch: linux/amd64
  Version: 4.1.1
```

**Package info (e.g. output of `rpm -q podman` or `apt list podman`):**

```
Auflistung… Fertig
podman/unbekannt,now 100:4.1.1-1 amd64  [installiert]
```

**Output of `podman login --get-login`:**

```
podman login --get-login
dennis605
```

Just to confirm the image exist and I should be able to pull it, Here the output of docker pull:

`docker pull docker.io/jc21/mariadb-aria:latest`

```
latest: Pulling from jc21/mariadb-aria
df20fa9351a1: Pull complete 
c4e214cb7f07: Pull complete 
568f83ab8cda: Pull complete 
edf866f7abc9: Pull complete 
a72600294fbb: Pull complete 
3e879d1f1b34: Pull complete 
41e2c76755f1: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:9dafab05f863cd186101fd8ac8b18684e8dfd7c3cce1376e552b77d0a8b40839
Status: Downloaded newer image for jc21/mariadb-aria:latest
docker.io/jc21/mariadb-aria:latest
```

`docker pull docker.io/jc21/mariadb-aria:latest`

```
podman pull --log-level=debug docker.io/jc21/mariadb-aria:latest


    INFO[0000] podman filtering at log level debug          
DEBU[0000] Called pull.PersistentPreRunE(podman pull --log-level=debug docker.io/jc21/mariadb-aria:latest) 
DEBU[0000] Merged system config "/usr/share/containers/containers.conf" 
DEBU[0000] environment variable PATH is already defined, skip the settings from containers.conf 
DEBU[0000] environment variable TERM is already defined, skip the settings from containers.conf 
DEBU[0000] Using conmon: "/usr/bin/conmon"              
DEBU[0000] Initializing boltdb state at /home/pod/.local/share/containers/storage/libpod/bolt_state.db 
DEBU[0000] Using graph driver overlay                   
DEBU[0000] Using graph root /home/pod/.local/share/containers/storage 
DEBU[0000] Using run root /run/user/1001/containers     
DEBU[0000] Using static dir /home/pod/.local/share/containers/storage/libpod 
DEBU[0000] Using tmp dir /run/user/1001/libpod/tmp      
DEBU[0000] Using volume path /home/pod/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes 
DEBU[0000] Set libpod namespace to ""                   
DEBU[0000] [graphdriver] trying provided driver "overlay" 
DEBU[0000] overlay: storage already configured with a mount-program 
DEBU[0000] backingFs=extfs, projectQuotaSupported=false, useNativeDiff=false, usingMetacopy=false 
DEBU[0000] Initializing event backend file              
DEBU[0000] Configured OCI runtime crun initialization failed: no valid executable found for OCI runtime crun: invalid argument 
DEBU[0000] Configured OCI runtime kata initialization failed: no valid executable found for OCI runtime kata: invalid argument 
DEBU[0000] Configured OCI runtime runsc initialization failed: no valid executable found for OCI runtime runsc: invalid argument 
DEBU[0000] Configured OCI runtime krun initialization failed: no valid executable found for OCI runtime krun: invalid argument 
DEBU[0000] Using OCI runtime "/usr/bin/runc"            
INFO[0000] Setting parallel job count to 13             
DEBU[0000] Pulling image docker.io/jc21/mariadb-aria:latest (policy: always) 
DEBU[0000] Looking up image "docker.io/jc21/mariadb-aria:latest" in local containers storage 
DEBU[0000] Normalized platform linux/amd64 to {amd64 linux  [] } 
DEBU[0000] Trying "docker.io/jc21/mariadb-aria:latest" ... 
DEBU[0000] Trying "docker.io/jc21/mariadb-aria:latest" ... 
DEBU[0000] Trying "docker.io/jc21/mariadb-aria:latest" ... 
DEBU[0000] Loading registries configuration "/etc/containers/registries.conf" 
DEBU[0000] Loading registries configuration "/etc/containers/registries.conf.d/000-shortnames.conf" 
DEBU[0000] Loading registries configuration "/etc/containers/registries.conf.d/shortnames.conf" 
DEBU[0000] Normalized platform linux/amd64 to {amd64 linux  [] } 
DEBU[0000] Attempting to pull candidate docker.io/jc21/mariadb-aria:latest for docker.io/jc21/mariadb-aria:latest 
DEBU[0000] parsed reference into "[overlay@/home/pod/.local/share/containers/storage+/run/user/1001/containers]docker.io/jc21/mariadb-aria:latest" 
Trying to pull docker.io/jc21/mariadb-aria:latest...
DEBU[0000] Copying source image //jc21/mariadb-aria:latest to destination image [overlay@/home/pod/.local/share/containers/storage+/run/user/1001/containers]docker.io/jc21/mariadb-aria:latest 
DEBU[0000] Trying to access "docker.io/library/jc21/mariadb-aria:latest" 
DEBU[0000] No credentials matching docker.io/library/jc21/mariadb-aria found in /run/user/1001/containers/auth.json 
DEBU[0000] No credentials matching docker.io/library/jc21/mariadb-aria found in /home/pod/.config/containers/auth.json 
DEBU[0000] Found credentials for docker.io/library/jc21/mariadb-aria in credential helper containers-auth.json in file /home/pod/.docker/config.json 
DEBU[0000] Using registries.d directory /etc/containers/registries.d for sigstore configuration 
DEBU[0000]  Using "default-docker" configuration        
DEBU[0000]  No signature storage configuration found for docker.io/library/jc21/mariadb-aria:latest, using built-in default file:///home/pod/.local/share/containers/sigstore 
DEBU[0000] Looking for TLS certificates and private keys in /etc/docker/certs.d/docker.io 
DEBU[0000] GET https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/         
DEBU[0000] Ping https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ status 401 
DEBU[0000] GET https://auth.docker.io/token?account=dennis605&scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fjc21%2Fmariadb-aria%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io 
DEBU[0000] GET https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/jc21/mariadb-aria/manifests/latest 
DEBU[0001] Content-Type from manifest GET is "application/json" 
DEBU[0001] Accessing "docker.io/library/jc21/mariadb-aria:latest" failed: reading manifest latest in docker.io/library/jc21/mariadb-aria: errors:
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
unauthorized: authentication required 
DEBU[0001] Error pulling candidate docker.io/jc21/mariadb-aria:latest: initializing source docker://jc21/mariadb-aria:latest: reading manifest latest in docker.io/library/jc21/mariadb-aria: errors:
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
unauthorized: authentication required 
Error: initializing source docker://jc21/mariadb-aria:latest: reading manifest latest in docker.io/library/jc21/mariadb-aria: errors:
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
unauthorized: authentication required
```

Comment: with podman 3 it also works, maybe a bug in podman 4?

Comment: podman-4-in-podman also works. strange.

Comment: have you tried logging *out* of docker.io?

Comment: Yes, but with podman 3, I unfortunately had other problems, so I had to update to podman 4. Regarding your question, yes I already tried to log out and log in again. But unfortunately without success. You wrote: “ podman-4-in-podman also works” that means it is working on your system with podman 4?

Comment: Have you tried studying verbose logs? `podman pull --log-level=debug docker.io/jc21/mariadb-aria:latest`

Comment: good idea. I really forget that - thanks. But I did it right now, and it is saying: ´´´DEBU[0001] Accessing "docker.io/library/jc21/mariadb-aria:latest" failed: reading manifest latest in docker.io/library/jc21/mariadb-aria: errors:
´´´ , but I'l add it to my qestion.

Comment: maybe put the whole log into a pastebin/gist. this also maybe really is a bug in podman, or at least a missing warning/error, better create an issue in GitHub. Or have they sent you here, your question looks like built using their issue template.

Comment: yes, you are right, I already raised a bug on github. My thought was, that maybe someone here as some additional ideas

Comment: then you should link the issue here. :)

Comment: I put the link in the description - thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Another idea: Create a new user account on your computer and test it out there. (Just to rule out the possibility that somehow the file contents in your home directory influences this)

Comment: This is really a good idea. I did it right now, but the result is the same.